# В чем разница между версиями Docker, и какую мне ставить?

Tags: docker

Начал изучать docker и уже не могу понять, почему есть три разные версии:

1. docker-ce
2. docker-engine
3. docker.io

В чём между ними разница? Какую мне лучше установить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`docker-engine`  и `docker.io` это устаревшие версии.

На данный момент актуальные версии это платная корпоративная версия (EE - Enterprise Edition) и бесплатная комьюнити-версия (CE - Сommunity  Edition).

Собственно `docker-ce` это бесплатная актуальная версия и устанавливать следует ее.

Если уже были установлены старые пакеты, то желательно удалить их перед установкой.

Удаление старых версий и установка новой:

- [Ubuntu/Debian](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/)
- [Centos/RHL](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/)

Comment: Бесплатную версию можно юзать в коммерческом ПО?  Какие плюхи в коммерческой версии?

Comment: @doox911 `docker-ce`  OpenSource под лицензией `Apache-2.0`. Можно использовать в коммерческом ПО, а так же изменять и распространять, но необходимо указывать авторство. Возможно есть какие-то юридические подводные камни, но в целом лицензия позволяет. 

С точки зрения основного функционала коммерческая версия ничем не отличается. Разница в том, что коммерческая версия включает в себя поддержку и сертифицированные решения, например: сканер уязвимостей,  LDAP/AD управление доступом с ролями и т.д. Более подробное сравнение [по ссылке](https://boxboat.com/2018/12/07/docker-ce-vs-docker-ee/)